# js_of_ocaml and event_listener

Tags: javascript, events, ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I have a div in js_of_ocaml which I want to assign an onmouseover event, like

`deck_div##onmouseover <- (fun () -> (* do stuff *) )`

However, the function type expected is

`(Dom_html.divElement Js.t, Dom_html.mouseEvent Js.t) Dom_html.event_listener`

How to construct this event listener? `deck_div` has no method `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was thinking about same question some months ago and AFAIR I have succeeded with Html.handler. Maybe this example will help you

https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml/blob/master/examples/hyperbolic/hypertree.ml#L276

```
let handle_drag element move stop click =
  let fuzz = 4 in
  element##onmousedown <- Html.handler
    (fun ev ->
       let x0 = ev##clientX and y0 = ev##clientY in
       ....
```

Comment: How do I correctly add explicit typing (type hint) to the `ev` argument here?